# No Power To Humidifier

Tags: furnace, humidifier

Hoping an expert here can help me out with an issue. I have a Goodman GMV9/GCV9 furnace and a General Aire 1042-L humidifier. When I went to replace the filter for the humidifier, I noticed it was dry and had no water going to the humidifier. My first initial thought was that the water line may be clogged (which it was) I got it cleaned up and still no water was going past the solenoid valve. My next thought was that the solenoid valve most likely needed to be replaced, so I went ahead and did so, as there was a build of calcium. After replacing the solenoid, there was still nothing flowing through it.

I decided to check the voltage of the wires going to the solenoid valve and saw that there was no power going to it. I went over to my furnace to find one of the wires from the humidifier out of the furnace. I believe when an HVAC person came during the winter, they replaced the board of my furnace, but never plugged this wire back in. I could be mistaken, but it doesn't seem right at all. The red wire is connected, but the white is loose and out of the furnace dangling.

I have provided pictures of the wires[image] and provided a picture of the circuit board, if anyone could please let me know where this wire should be placed and how to do so, I would truly appreciate it.

Thank you so much in advance!

[image: Both Images]

[image: All images]

Comment: Perhaps the ambient humidity is higher than the humidity setting.  (It thinks it's already humid enough so doesn't send power to the solenoid).

Comment: How about a picture of where the white wire is connected (at the other end) and a close up picture of the connections on the furnace so that the labeling is actually readable. The overview pic is good, but it can't be read.

Comment: Talk to the HVAC people and see what they have to say.